# Split string in a column into three columns in the same table and insert it into new table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I am a beginner here.. here is my question

I have a table "tspade" with two columns that is shown below :

```
No  | Unixdatetime                                      |

1   | 1234567890 -1 #SUP: 2                             |

2   | 2345678901 -1 #SUP: 2                             |

3   | 3456789012 -1 #SUP: 3                             |

4   | 4567890123 -1 5678901234 -1 #SUP: 2               |

5   | 6789012345 -1 7890123456 -1 8901234567 -1 #SUP: 2 |
```

---

I'd like to convert that table into like this :

```
No  | Unixdatetime1 | Unixdatetime2 | Unixdatetime3 |

1   | 1234567890    | 0             | 0             |

2   | 2345678901    | 0             | 0             |

3   | 3456789012    | 0             | 0             |

4   | 4567890123    | 5678901234    | 0             |

5   | 6789012345    | 7890123456    | 8901234567    |
```

---

and save that to table `try`

I used this query :

```
Insert Into try (No,Unixdatetime1,Unixdatetime2,Unixdatetime3)
SELECT `No`, `Unixdatetime`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', 1 ) AS Unixdatetime1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1) AS Unixdatetime2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', -1 ) AS Unixdatetime3
FROM tspade
```

but it couldn't work...
Any advice or help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any errors/warnings when executing the query?

Answer (score 0):

You try to Insert **4** columns with SELECT which select **5** columns :

```
Insert Into try (No, Unixdatetime1, Unixdatetime2,Unixdatetime3)
--               1       2             3            4
SELECT 
   `No`, -- <--------1
   `Unixdatetime`, -- <--------2
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', 1 ) 
    AS Unixdatetime1, -- <--------3
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1) 
    AS Unixdatetime2,-- <--------4
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', -1 ) 
    AS Unixdatetime3 -- <--------5
FROM tspade
```

and this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

4 column in value and 5 in insert

(and you should not  use alias for select ) in insert select  the number and data type of column in value cluase and in select cluase must match

eg :

```
  Insert Into try (No,Unixdatetime1,Unixdatetime2,Unixdatetime3)
  SELECT `No`
      ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', 1 ) 
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1) 
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Unixdatetime` , ' -1 ', -1 ) 
  FROM tspade
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be selecting the values. Forget about `SELECT INTO` if you don't know 100% what you are doing.

```
Select No, SUBSTRING(...) as Date1, [...] from tspade
```

Replace the ellipsis with the code you need to select the substrings as you want them on your result table (watch the result!).

When you have the results you need in your `Select` result, insert that into the next table.

```
Insert Into try(No, Unixdatetime1, Unixdatetime2, Unixdatetime3 )
Select No, SUBSTRING(...) as Date1, [...] from tspade
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the no. of columns in the try table and the select statement are not matching.

SELECT No, **Unixdatetime**, SUBSTRING_INDEX( Unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 1 ) AS Unixdatetime1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( Unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1) AS Unixdatetime2, SUBSTRING_INDEX( Unixdatetime , ' -1 ', -1 ) AS Unixdatetime3 FROM tspade

Remove the highlighted column from select statement and then try.